# Retrieve from Firebase - Index Out of Bounds

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, indexoutofboundsexception

**Immediate Goal: Retrieve data from Firebase so that I can display it to Log Info in Android**

Long term goal: Retrieve data from Firebase so I can display it in a TextView or otherview

---

*Research*: Youtube, Google, Stackoverflow, and Firebase documentation (specifically https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

What else i've tried: I've tried catching the error or having condition where if theres nothing it just sends a log, that doesn't actually fix the error though, just makes sure it doesn't crash.

---

**Error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                                at com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.RegisterSubscriptionActivity.onCreate(RegisterSubscriptionActivity.java:80)
```

*Error is happening at this line:
eNum = subscriptionInfo.get(0).toString();*

I'm not sure I understand the DataSnapshot.. specificall the .getValue method

---

**Firebase DB**:
[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL21W.jpg)

**RegisterSubscriptionActivity.java**:

```
public class RegisterSubscriptionActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    ArrayList subscriptionInfo;

    //Subscription (String) values
    String micro, small, medium, large, enterprise;
    String mNum, sNum, medNum, lNum, eNum;
    String mPrice, sPrice, medPrice, lPrice, ePrice;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_subscription);

        subscriptionInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        //GET INSTANCE OF FIREBASE DB & GRAB SUBSCRIPTION DATA
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("Subscription").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //get everything UNDER subscription
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //literally a "snapshot" of the data

                for(DataSnapshot subscriptionDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String subscriptions = subscriptionDataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    subscriptionInfo.add(subscriptions);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        //MICRO
        //mNum = subscriptionInfo.get(6).toString();
       // mPrice = subscriptionInfo.get(7).toString();
       // micro = subscriptionInfo.get(11).toString();
        //ENTERPRISE
        eNum = subscriptionInfo.get(0).toString();
        Log.i("enterprise number", eNum);
```

Please help me understand what I am missing or where I need to look further, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Reading data from Firebase [is asynchronous](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).**

That means that the results (likely) aren't stored in `subscriptionInfo` yet when you are trying to access the first element:

```
eNum = subscriptionInfo.get(0).toString();
```

An attempt to access an index of an ArrayList that doesn't exist results in the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you are facing.

---

You could **move the logging step into the event handler**:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot subscriptionDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String subscriptions = subscriptionDataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            subscriptionInfo.add(subscriptions);
        }
    }

    eNum = subscriptionInfo.get(0).toString();
    Log.i("enterprise number", eNum);
}
```

Comment: Hi Timo, thanks for your input, I think I understand what you are saying about it being asynchronous and hence why you modified the code as you did. I tried using this though and am getting "unknown class eNum" as well as "cannot resolve symbol get" (for eNum = subscriptionInfo.get(0).toString();)

Comment: So I tried placing that part of the code inside the for loop to get rid of the errors, but there is no log printed to the screen whatsoever....which makes me wonder if it's even getting to the onDataChange ?